# Would questions about a chess book values be on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I'm aware the questions about the value of a chess set are off-topic, however I'm wondering if questions about book values are on-topic. Specifically, I'm curious about why a certain book tends to be somewhat difficult to find, and is  priced so high.

Comment: As a non-collector, I know when I read about an out of print book, I'd love to know if it's worth the money. Even though I check a lot of books out via interlibrary loan/worldcat, this would be a useful resource to me so I don't use my interlibrary loans on weak books. So I think this is a great question, though I don't know enough site rules to know if it would fit in stackoverflow chess.

Comment: @aschultz: Just look at reviews on Amazon, or read it yourself. If you see value in it when no one is leaving reviews, it's good to ask for someone to leave a review. **It's good to ask why it's valuable** (the book's main ideas); **it's not good to ask why it's difficult to find** (the lack of supply or the excessive demand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a fine question, as long as you don't ask people for (an estimate of) the value of the book, which is *primarily opinion-based* (not off-topic, but it will be closed anyway). Incidentally, there's no reason why this shouldn't apply for chess sets, chess clocks and chess computers as well.

The close reason 'primarily opinion-based' reads:

> **Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience**, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

(emphasis mine). I think this could be one of those 'good questions' the reason refers to.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask about the general valuation of chess books in the context of chess, it is probably a valid question. But these days a strong chess engine with a group of humans (seconds) to help with the interpretation of engine evaluations, should render most books unnecessary or obsolete.

Also, similar to computer books, chess books are in a niche market with limited value as their content becomes outdated quickly (reduced information value), even publishers are increasingly switching to ebooks which are sold for a lower price.

Answer (score -1):

No. The answer is simply *supply and demand.* We can extrapolate this to any valuable object, and find that the answer is the same.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think that questions like this should be marked as a duplicate. "Why is product X worth P price?", and the answer always has the format of "because of supply and demand".

Comment: That's not completely true, see https://money.stackexchange.com/q/79848 for example.